# Run Configuration for Android JUnit tests across multiple modules possible?

Tags: unit-testing, android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea, run-configuration

Is it possible to define a run configuration in Android Studio (IntelliJ), which runs unit tests of more than just one specific module?

I have many modules in my app and I want to test everything with just a single command, without triggering each module´s run config one by one.